# Remove all characters after the fourth space in a string

Tags: c#, string

I want to remove all characters after the fourth space in a string.

**Example**:

> **Source:** AAD BCCD QWD SDKE DJQWEK DJT
>
> **Result:** AAD BCCD QWD SDKE

I tried to use 'String.indexof'. but, I couldn't.

Here is my code:

```
Result = source.Substring(source.IndexOf(string.Empty, source.IndexOf(string.Empty) + 3));
```

Comment: `var result = string.Join(" ", source.Split(' ').Take(4));`

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
string result = string.Join(" ", source.Split(' ').Take(4));
```

This splits the original `source` string at each space character, takes the first 4 occurrences and concatenates them with a space character.
It will also work correctly in cases where there are less than 4 counts of spaces in the source string.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this (if it's still actuall of course):

```
string Source = "AAD BCCD QWD SDKE DJQWEK DJT"
int space = GetNthIndex(Source, ' ', 4);
string result = sample.Substring(0, space);
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `GetNthIndex` out of the box in C# ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a loop with a counter and check each character. Pseudocode:

```
    counter = 0;
    foreach(character in string)
        if(counter > 4)
            exit;
        else if(character == space)
            counter++;
            output character
        else
            output character
```